# Selecting tests by parameter in NUnit 3 console

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I have tests parameterized with `ValueSource` attribute. The source provides 3 parameters (these are environments to run the test in) and I can see and select them in Test Explorer in Visual Studio.
But how do I select specific parameters when using NUnit console runner? I tried `--params environmentId:prod`, but it does not work (tests for all three environments are executed).

P.S: `environmentId` is my test method's parameter name and "prod" is one of three values provided with `ValueSource` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of misunderstanding implied in the question regarding the `--params` option. It doesn't select tests but passes information to the tests, which may be accessed using the `TestContext`. And it has no connection at all with the parameters of test cases that take arguments.

You have two ways to go here: (1) figure out the right way to select the test cases from the command-line as you are currently trying to do or (2) actually use the `--params` option in the intended way. Note that these are mutually exclusive options.

1. Selecting the correct cases.

   Every test case has a name, which includes the arguments. You can select the correct cases using an expression that indentifies the ones you want and eliminates the ones you don't want. For example, the option `--where "test==Your.Name.Space.YourMethod"` would select all the cases for a given method. To select those cases with just the "prod" option, you might use a regular expression... perhaps something like `--where "test=~/Your\.Name\.Space\.YourMethod\(prod/` assuming the argument in question is the first one. Obviously, this is not an easy command-line to type, so the second option may look better to you.
2. Using `--params` correctly

   Based on the name of the `environmentID` parameter, I'm guessing you might want to run **all** your tests using the same value rather than changing it in the course of a test run. That's the purpose of **run parameters** as passed to your application by the `--params` option. Using `--params:environmentID=prod` sets up the test run so that any tests needing the correct `environmentID` can easily access it. You would no longer use `environmentID` as a C# parameter to your test method but would access the value in the body of the test with code like

   `string environmentID = TestContext.Parameters.Get("environmentID");`

   You may also provide a second argument to `Get`, specifying the environment to use if no parameter is passed.

Hopefully, one of these two approaches will work for you!